# Android Studio Bumblebee is not able to read FilePaths in Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I updated to the Bumblebee version and now the building process is failing with this error:

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > path may not be null
> or empty string. path='null'

the line where the error is happening is this one:

```
 if (file(System.getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS")).exists())
```

This is really strange is it means that the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS doesn't exist?

If I echo the variable on the terminal it exists and the file that makes reference to that variable also exists, I didn't find any solution so I rolled back to the Artic version and It worked like a charm, but this is a stopper to migrate to the new version. Do have anyone found any solution to this?

Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem with System.getenv in mac. As a workaround I'm launching the Android Studio from the console and is working: /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio

Thanks!